# webkit problem printing XPathResults, need workaround

Tags: android, safari, webkit, google-chrome-extension, xpath

I'm using the following code...

```
 var result = document.evaluate(expr,context,null,9,null);
```

When printing the result I get the following error...

```
Error: TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52
```

This appears to be an issue with webkit in general as evident from the following issue...

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68770

I'm wondering, does anyone know of a workaround way I can make this work? The work around need only suit just webkit. It does not needed to work in Firefox, IE, etc.

**NOTE:** I myself am working with Google Chrome but I've included the other popular applications which use webkit since this issue is relevant to them too.

**EDIT:** Same result when I call `screenshotLength()` on `result`.

**EDIT 2**

```
var result = document.evaluate(expr,context,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```

Appears to produce `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! It wasn't webkit but rather the way I was calling this function. All `document.evaluate` calls in Chrome shouldn't be made in the `background.html`. Worked from a content script for me.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by this solution? Are you saying that using the background.html as the context argument will not work when the evaluate method is called from that document?