# Selecting element from DOM with JavaScript and XPath

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to select the textarea in the code below using xpath and JavaScript (which is the only option here).

```
<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="calculatorController">
            <form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
                <p>
                    <textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
                </p>
            </form>
        ...
```

I'm trying to do something like this

```
var element = document.evaluate( '//body/form/p/textarea' ,document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
// and write back
element.value = "Hello textarea";
```

But it fails

Anyone keen to help?

Thanks

**Update below this**

============================================================

The entire block of code looks like this.
Don't forget the `window.onload=function()`

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
  //<![CDATA[ 
  window.onload=function(){
  var element = document.evaluate( '//body//form/p/textarea' ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;

        if (element != null) {
            element.value = 'Hello textarea';
        }

  }
  //]]> 
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="calculatorController">
            <form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
                <p>
                    <textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm no XPath expert but wouldn't the path need to be '//body/div/div/form/p/textarea'??

Comment: I see, you put the javascript in your head section, it will execute before the DOM is loaded, try either put your code just before </body> or in the head, put your code in a function and add `window.onload = function_name;`

Comment: Aaaaaand, you beat me to it before I post it :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The evaluate method does not return a DOM node as you seem to expect. You would need

```
var element = document.evaluate( '//body//form/p/textarea' ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
if (element != null) {
  element.value = '...';
}
```

Comment: Ooh, nice solution, proper than mine.

Comment: yes it [does](http://jsfiddle.net/5A6WW/) , maybe you're using a browser not compatible with evaluate?

Comment: Firefox 5, Chrome 12, Safari 5, all in mac os. Tried to run them both locally and from a webserver *arghs*

Comment: Tried his code locally on FF4 and chromium 14 here, no problems at all

Comment: Thanks, the jsfiddle helped med out :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in IE. Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 2):

@Mark Robinson comment is right, your Xpath expression is wrong, you could use one of those :

```
//body/div/div/form/p/textarea (Mark's example)
//body//form/p/textarea (any form in body)
```

Plus, the evaluate function will return a [XPathResult](http://help.dottoro.com/ljagksjc.php) object, not the textarea, so you can't do directly element.value

Here is your example fixed:

```
<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="calculatorController">
            <form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
                <p>
                    <textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

--

```
var element = document.evaluate( '//body/div/div/form/p/textarea' ,document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

var textarea = element.iterateNext ();
textarea.value = "Hello textarea";
```

Comment: It tend to return Error: TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806015/webkit-problem-printing-xpathresults-need-workaround) or [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68770) will help?