# Parsing Data from HTML without IDs

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I want to parse (with Javascript or JSoup) an Website.
My Problem is that I don´t knew how to access the wanted data, because in that file are practically no Ids.

I have something like:

```
           <div id content>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align >
<div style=>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
    <tr>

    <td>
    <br></br>
    <h2><div class=""></div>Related</h2>

    Adaptation: 
    <a href="/link">nameOfBook</a>
    <br></br>

    Prequel: 
    <a href="/link2">nameOfBook2</a>
    <br></br>

    Other: 

    <a href="link3"></a>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <h2></h2>
    <table width0"></table>
    ..........many tables and a.....
    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hopefully its understandable, the site is quite big. 
I want the Stuff after Related.
So I want the Sequel connected with the three names and their links. 
And then the Prequel name3.

At the moment I get the #content then I get the Array with all h2 Tags and check the 2nd child, if it equals to "Related".
Then I get the parent (td) and iterate over all "a".
In this one td are over 200 a´s.

My plan was now to iterate over those and check if before that "a" comes the term (prequel, sequel or adaption), but it sounds a little bit complicated.

Or I could parse everything between the two h2 Tags, because it´s always there. Or, I could check the link, because the wanted ones have always the same structure. So, search for that structure and then go to the parent and check what term it is.

Anyone can help me with that? In the whole document are no id´s or names.
I am pretty sure, that I can find an workaround for that, but it would be just too complicated and with some JS Knowledge easy to get.

UPDAtE:

It´s not known how many Prequel/Sequel whatever Tags will be there.
The only thing I really knew is that there will be an "Related" Text between two h2-Tags and the next beginning h2 is the start of something new.

And changed the above example: now it´s the correct Structure, #content is again in an div, but I guess that´s not important because I can access content directly.

Comment: Show us your JS, it would be easier to understand and help ;).

Comment: I advise to use **DOM** and **XPath**. 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466831/selecting-element-from-dom-with-javascript-and-xpath

Comment: Are you sure about your markup with `<tr> <td>` outside of the table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` and select the element in a relative manner.

For example:
to select first three `a` tags within div[id='content']

```
var allAnchorsInDiv = document.querySelectorAll("div[id='content'] a"); //Basically this is an array of anchors.
//select anchors from array.
```

If you don't have any Ids at all, then you should probably use a relative path (something like Xpath or CSS selector).

Using CSS selector you will use something like this,

```
document.querySelectorAll('body>div:first-of-type>a');
```

Or you could use XPath, refer [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)

**Note:** If you want things a little easier you could even use jquery to accomplish the same.

**Update:**

So, for your need you have to do this.

1. Select the text node with the text.
2. Find the node anchor nodes next to it.

Thus,

```
var myKeyTerm = "Sequel"; //Set your keyterm here.
var myAnchorTags = [];
var myTextNode = document.evaluate("//text()[contains(., '"+myKeyTerm +"')]" ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
if(myTextNode) {
    var nextNode = myTextNode;
    do {
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling;
        if(nextNode && nextNode.nodeName == "A") {
            myAnchorTags.push(nextNode);
        }
        else nextNode = null;
    }
    while(nextNode);
}
//All the nodes that follow your required text is in myAnchorTags array.
```

Comment: ohh didn´t knew that I can use XPAtH with js. No, the first example would return over 80 elements, how should I differentiate them? The 2nd one would return my first "a", right? Then I can get the other ones with .nexSibling and so on. But, how do I get the Sequel/Prequel Text?

Comment: This might help you start with XPath in js http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp. And edited my answer a little bit (separated Xpath and CSS selector) for better clarity.

Comment: Thanks, and I eddited my comment :) I still press Enter when i want to make an paragraph :/

Comment: I have updated my answer :). This should be helpful.

Comment: @Nemos if you don't want any filter then find the text node without contains function.

Comment: Thank you very much that gets the job done. Going to check out XPATH seems that it can help sometimes :O But for what do I need the "A" condition[ohh okay it´s clear :D]?  And it seems that it´s not working with more than one link, only one is shown.

Comment: Now I see the error. Between the <a> Tags from the same Entry (Sequel,...) are ",", so I guess these also count as nextSibling. So I added else if(nextNode && nextNode.nodeName==','){ , but nothing changes. If i add  alert(nextNode.nodeName); after the nextNode assignment it only shows util the link and then aborts.

Comment: Okay, I have to use nodeValue and compare it. Now I can see that the stuff what I want is pushed to the Array. But if I want to access that data after the while I am not able to get it. In fact if I use anything after the while it´s never executed.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var h2 = content.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]; // the first h2 element
var link1 = h2.nextElementSibling;
var link2 = link1.nextElementSibling;
var link3 = link2.nextElementSibling;
var link4 = link3.nextElementSibling;
console.log("Sequel: ", link1.innerHTML, link1.href);
console.log("Sequel: ", link2.innerHTML, link2.href);
console.log("Sequel: ", link3.innerHTML, link3.href);
console.log("Prequel: ", link4.innerHTML, link4.href);
```

This method has the advantage of working even if there are links inside the first (stripped out) `table`.

But it won't work if the first (stripped out) `table` contains `h2` elements... In that case, instead of

```
var h2 = content.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]; // the first h2 element
```

You should use

```
var h2 = Array.prototype.filter.call(content.children, function(c) {return c.tagName.toLowerCase() == "h2"})[0];
```

## EDIT

```
function listlinks(){
var prequels = [];
var sequels = [];
var all_h2_elems = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var h2_start = Array.prototype.filter.call(all_h2_elems, function(el){return el.innerText.indexOf("Related") != -1})[0];
var parent = h2_start.parentElement;
var h2_elems = Array.prototype.filter.call(parent.children, function(c) {return c.tagName.toLowerCase() == "h2"});
if (h2_elems.length < 2) console.log("You lied, you said there were always 2 h2 tags!");
if (!h2_start.isSameNode(h2_elems[0])) console.log("Hmmm, there should not be a h2 tag before the 'Related' one, fix your question.");
var sequel = false;
var prequel = false;
var current = h2_elems[0];
var end = h2_elems[1]
while(current && !current.isSameNode(end))
{
  if (current.tagName === undefined)
  {
    if (current.nodeValue.indexOf("Sequel") != -1)
    {
      if (sequel || prequel) { console.log("wtf? another sequel?"); break; }
      sequel = true;
    }
    else if (current.nodeValue.indexOf("Prequel") != -1)
    {
      if (!sequel) { console.log("wtf? prequel should be AFTER sequel"); break; }
      prequel = true;
      sequel = false;
    }
    else if (current.nodeValue.match(/[a-z]/)){
      prequel = false;
      sequel = false;
      // stop outputing links if anything else is found
    }
  } // end if (current.tagName === undefined)
  else if (current.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a")
  {
    if (prequel) prequels.push(current.innerHTML + " : " + current.href);
    if (sequel) sequels.push(current.innerHTML + " : " + current.href);
  }
  current = current.nextSibling;
}
  return [prequels,sequels];
}
listlinks().forEach(function(el,i){console.log(i?"Sequels:":"Prequels:",el)})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don´t knew how many Elementts which I need will be in the HTML. So, an static way is probably not working. I edited my starting post.

Comment: There you go. All links, regardless of anything else in the page output in the console.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the markup changing -_-' I'll fix that

Comment: Adapted to the new markup, and to any markup to be honest. I looked for the `h2` tag containing `Related`, started storing links when I encountered `Sequel` and continued until I reached a text matching neither `Sequel` nor `Prequel`. If you want to match `Adaptation` instead of `Sequel`, change the `indexOf("Sequel")` part.

Comment: Thanks. Seems a little bit complicated for me. Have to think it thru, maybe I can use it for something different.

Comment: What do you need for it to be usable?