# Codeception - click on xpath using executeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, codeception

I want to use executeJS from Codeception to click on an element for which I'm using a xpath locator. I know this is very simple when using it with `document.getElementById`. But I've tried using it with an xpath, and I can't make it to work. The line that's giving me headaches is :
`$this->executeJS('$(\'(//*[@id="openOrders-table"]/tbody/tr[contains(., "Open")]//button[@type="button"])[1]\').click();');` it gives: `Cannot read property 'click' of null`

If I do a search in the DOM, it finds the element, everything is ok if I use it without JS.

The reason for which I want to ise JS is because the click from JS automatically scrolls to the element and clicks on it. The `scrollTo` from Codeception doesn't help me much. the element is not in the same place all the time. Appreciate the time guys!

Comment: You should use css, please provide the HTML snippet of the form if possible if you need help in getting the css selector. For xpath take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466831/selecting-element-from-dom-with-javascript-and-xpath

Comment: css is not an option unfortunately, as I'm selecting parent/child/child, because it's a table of multiple lines, and there are multiple elements with the same id/class. This is the only selector option that narrows it down to a unique element, the first line with `Open` status. The xpath is correct, as I've stated before, I'm able to find it in the DOM by pressing CRTL+F then pasting the xpath expression, it returns 1 result, the desired button.